# Can't unpack file created with python tarfile, update time modification denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, permissions, gzip, tar

I'm using Python 2.7. I have a .tar.gz file I create using the python tarfile library that unpacks into /opt. However when I try to unpack it using:

```
tar -xPzvf myfile.tar.gz
```

I get the following error:

```
tar: /: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

It looks like the tar file is trying to modify the last modified time directly? I looked into the options tarfile provides but couldn't find anything relevant other than the actual modification time.

Comment: What command are you using to untar?

Comment: tar -xPzvf myfile.tar.gz

Comment: What happens if you loose the -P (preserve) flag, and just use -zvf

Comment: Isn't -P (capital P) the absolute names tag? According to:

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar

This is necessary to have it unpack into /opt instead of an opt directory relative to where I run the command (./opt), I think.

Comment: Do you have write permission to /opt?

Comment: No, but my tar file extracts to /opt/foo/... and i have write access to foo. I have extracted other tarballs this way on the same machine but only the ones created with python are giving this error.

Edit: That is the tarball starts extracting at /opt but only writes into a sub directory /opt/foo and nothing else in /opt

Comment: I suspect this is more a tar issue -- rather than specifically a python issue. For example, it's possible some attribute required to be updated to the parent folder (ie: /opt), which was denied. What if instead of doing '-P', you chain a cd command in front of the extraction, and perform relative extraction, eg: (cd /opt/foo && tar -xvf /path/to/tarfile.tar)

Comment: Unfortunately, this tar file is going to be inserted into a pre-existing process that I am powerless to change. If it's relevant: the tarball does not have a TarInfo object (from the tarfile library) for "/" or "/opt".

Comment: How did you create the tarfile? Something in there is trying to update /opt. Unless you can stop that (or invoke tar extract in a way that does not try to update /opt) -- your stuck

Answer (score 0):

You try to unpack to `/opt` directory, that you don't permission for that .

For example, if you want to create a file in `/opt` by normal `user`, you get this error:

```
$ touch  /opt/test
touch: cannot touch ‘/opt/test’: Permission denied
```

Try to unpack it to another directory, for example: `/home/YOUR_USER/`

Comment: Is this relevant given that the python is not interacting with the opt directory directly? To clarify: My python script does not unpack the tar file, I try to manually unpack a tar file I created with Python.The error I posted is from tar, not python.

Comment: It seems, the `tar` command is trying to modify date/time (can be off by `-m`, `--touch` option) of a directory with the current user, Although the current user has write access to that directory, but the current user is not owner of  that directory, so you needs to make the current user as owner of that directory. read about [here](http://portal2portal.blogspot.nl/2011/01/doh-error-tar-cannot-utime-operation.html)